# Find volume of the body $V = \{ z = \sqrt{6-x^2-y^2}, z = x^2 + y^2 \}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find volume of the body $V = \{  z = \sqrt{6-x^2-y^2}, z = x^2 + y^2 \}$

Now what I said is:

$$V = \iint_{D} {\sqrt{6-x^2-y^2} - x^2 - y^2 dxdy}$$.
But when I wanted to get what $D$ is, I intersected the two $z$ functions to get $\sqrt{6-x^2-y^2} = x^2+y^2$.
But what is this $D$? It is certainly not a circle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea: the intersection of

$$z=x^2+y^2\;,\;\;z=\sqrt{6-x^2-y^2}\implies z=\sqrt{6-z}\implies 0=z^2+z-6=(z+3)(z-2)$$

Since $\,z=-3\,$ is absurd (why?),  we then have $\;2=z=x^2+y^2\;$ and you can now get easily your limits in the $\,xy-plane\;$ by means of this canonical circle.

Comment: I did not understand what you meant by "Since $z = -3$.."

Comment: Just look what the surfaces defined by $\,z\,$ are...

Comment: Oh. If I understood correctly, it comes from the fact that $z=x^2+y^2$ that $z$ can not be a negative number. And for that, we cancel $z+3$ and we get $0=z-2=x^2 + y^2 - 2 \rightarrow x^2+y^2 = 2$ and $D$ is our last equation.
Yes?

Comment: None of the two surfaces is negative, not only the one you mention, and we do **not** cancel anything: from $\,(z+3)(z-2)=0\;$ we get that either$\,z=-3\;$ or $\;z=2\;$ . The first one's impossible in the present case, so it **must** be $\;z=2\;$ *in the intersection between the surfaces*, of course.

Comment: After that I got $V ~= 7.52$. Did you get the same?

Comment: Well, I didn't do it, but after I did it I get $$\frac{\pi}3\left(12\sqrt6-22\right)\cong 7.743$$

Comment: Thank you, much appreciated.